# How to cancel a flag?

Tags: support, bug

I started this question and the AI immediately pointed me to a duplicate.  But the answer to that duplicate didn’t work.  Now the AI isn’t finding that duplicate, so I’ll have to ask again.

I flagged a good answer by accident as “not an answer.”  The Answer on the duplicate said that if I tap to flag again, I will see a button to reverse my flag.  Tried it—not true.

Is there a way that works with the current version of SE?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already raised a non-custom flag, click ‘flag’ again and in the dialog that opens choose ‘Retract Flag’ from the ‘Flag Question’/‘Flag Answer’ button in the bottom right (the text changes to ‘Retract Flag’ and is enabled without a flag option selected).

Comment: That’s what the answer I saw previously said.  And as I wrote, it isn’t true now if it was then.  I tried (as I said) and there was no such link.  And now, I don’t remember the question to find it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Asking for more help here is an excellent way if flagging alone doesn’t help.

Also, not an answer flags are among the least acted upon. Moderators almost never have to take binding action on poor answers since almost anyone can edit them to turn them into answers or vote them down if they are not useful. The bar is high for us to do anything other than decline or mark as helpful NAA flags in practice. Just ignoring bad answers works very well in practice if you aren’t sure you want to downvote or leave a constructive comment.

As for other issues, all flags here are processed, so carry on with your main actions. No need for worrying about the past flag as it’s already been handled.